# yum update got error 404 with an URL on https://cdn.redhat.com/

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, snap

I am trying to install **Snap Store** and **Octave** on RHEL7 following the [official instruction](https://snapcraft.io/install/octave/rhel).

However, the command `yum update` got stuck on an error saying, `https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found`.

I have tried the following attempts for troubleshooting, but they did not help.

- follow https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623
- set `sslverify=false` in file `/etc/yum.conf`
- use the browser to access and get "Access Denied" for the link https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml

Eventually I tried `yum-config-manager --save --setopt=rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rpms.skip_if_unavailable=true`, and it helped.

I wonder what I missed in the steps above, and I hope to fix the error and set up all the YUM repos correctly.

Any hints or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

**Screenshot:**

```
[root@rhel-desktop ~]# yum update --verbose
Not loading "rhnplugin" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "langpacks" plugin
Loading "product-id" plugin
Loading "search-disabled-repos" plugin
Loading "subscription-manager" plugin
Adding en_US.UTF-8 to language list
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Config time: 2.311
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.000
Updating Everything
Building updates object
Setting up Package Sacks
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                                        |  19 kB  00:00:00     
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                                                                                                   | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.2 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                                                                          | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
pkgsack time: 2.907
up:Obs Init time: 0.484
up:simple updates time: 0.030
up:obs time: 0.004
up:condense time: 0.000
updates time: 3.817
No packages marked for update
```

Comment: This could be an issue that clears itself up on its own. How to know? Just wait a day or so and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Giacomo1968. I just tried again today, and the error still stays. Also, the cdn.redhat.com website returns "Access Denied" for the link.